# STI, sublasses and failing validations

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, validation, single-table-inheritance

I am having a hard time figuring what the hell is going on here.

I have a model Page and it has two subclasses called QeopPage and GymPage. I am trying to create a gympage but the validations in both classes keep failing with `'Validation failed: Title can't be blank, Meta description can't be blank'`

```
class GymPage < Page
  self.set_table_name="pages"               

  validates :meta_description, presence:true

end

class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :title, :presence=>true

end
```

I thought it might be a params issue, but there is nothing in my server logs to indicate this. I can make a gympage in the console....
Here is the relevant server log snippet

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"ULWHNAM71V3T+tEgYFaJfWtIQ7twYwktmdo6OSduiYE=", "gym_page"=>{"meta_title"=>"esfwef", "meta_description"=>"wefwefwef", "title"=>"wefwefwef", "body"=>"wefwef", "slug"=>"about", "asset_attachment_title"=>""}, "commit"=>"Update page", "venue_id"=>"venue_one"}
  Admin Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  `admins`.* FROM `admins`  WHERE `admins`.`id` = 633  ORDER BY `admins`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
  Venue Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  `venues`.* FROM `venues`  WHERE `venues`.`slug` = 'mitre-passage-8754d82e-8eeb-4d9f-91e4-c13b3661991c'  ORDER BY venues.title ASC LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  Admin Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  `admins`.* FROM `admins`   ORDER BY `admins`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
  Admin Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `admins`.* FROM `admins`  WHERE `admins`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1
  Banner Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `banners`.* FROM `banners`  WHERE `banners`.`id` IS NULL LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  `banners`.* FROM `banners`  WHERE `banners`.`id` IS NULL LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 998ms
```

I should add that the controller is working as expected - the parameters are being passed correctly.

What the hell is going on?!

## update

controller code

```
  def create 
    @gym_page = GymPage.new(params[:gym_page_params])
    @gym_page.admin=current_admin
    if @gym_page.save!
      flash[:notice] = 'Page created'
      redirect_to admin_venue_gym_pages_path(@venue)
    else
      flash[:error] = 'There was an error'
      render :new
    end
  end
```

Comment: can you post controller code?the error may come from there

Comment: use `@gym_page =  GymPage.new(params[:gym_page])`. As per the request log gym page attributes are passed inside gym_page.

Answer (score 1):

As per the request log gym page attributes are passed inside gym_page so you need to do following in you controller

```
@gym_page = GymPage.new(params[:gym_page])
```